# Unique Copy and Paste Function

Tags: microsoft-excel, copy-paste

I am 99% sure this isn't possible but I really, really hope I'm wrong. Is there any way to take a column of data that has cells with values in it, but also has random blank cells in it as well, and paste it into another column that has those blank cells filled in with formulas that need to remain, such that the cells with values in them are overridden by the pasted values, but the blank cells that are being pasted in DO NOT override the formulas that are present?  This would save me so much time...  Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can create a new column with the values you want by copying `=IF(ISBLANK(A1,B1,A1))` down the column, assuming `A` is the source column and `B` the target. You can then hide column `B`.

Comment: Note that `ISBLANK()` should really be named `ISEMPTY()`.  If a cell appears blank, but has a formula in it, `ISBLANK()` will return FALSE for that cell, and AFH's formula will "paste" the formula that gives the blank cell.

Answer (score 2):

Paste Special > tick "Skip Blanks" -- The animated screenshot has formulas in the yellow cells, which survive the pasting and continue to calculate correctly.

[image]